# how to do clustering when the input is 3D matrix, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

i am having 3D matrix in which most of the values are zeros but there are some nonzeros values.

when I am plotting this 3D matrix in matlab I am getting plot like as below

here u can see there are two groups of points are nearer to each other(that's why the color became dark) and two individual group of points is far away....

[image]

so my objective is to cluster that two nearer group of points and make it as one cluster1 and other two will be called as cluster2 and cluster3 ....

I tried kmeans clustering, BIC clustering...but as kmeans clustering is basically build up for 2D data input, I faced hurdle there ...then I reshape 3D matrix into 2D matrix but still I am getting another error ***Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch***

so could u plz come out with some fruitful idea to do this......

Comment: I don't think e.g. `kmeans` is build for clustering 2D data

Comment: Just remember that you have to arrange your `n` 3D points in an `n x 3` matrix

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried your suggestion. my input matrix size is 100*17*25 hence I reshape  it into 2D matrix like [100*17   25]. but still i ma getting error "Empty cluster created at iteration 1".

Comment: You have to build an `n x 3` matrix. Bring your points into the form `point = [velocity, range, angle]`. And then you have arranged them as a `n x 3` matrix.

Comment: How did you plot the 3D matrix? If you tell us, we will be better able to understand what transform you need for your array.

Comment: yes sure,I used vol3d function to plot 3D matrix.

Comment: If you just want to split that data set, define thresholds based on your visualization. i.e. angle >0°; angle < -5°; inbetween.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Also, for clustering: I understand that two points should be considered similar if they are close in space and close in value? Finally: there are a lot of zeros or NaNs in your 3D matrix, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment that you used `vol3d` I assume that your data has to interpreted this way. If your data-matrix is called `M`, try

```
[A,B,C] = ind2sub(size(M),find(M));
points = [A,B,C];
idx = kmeans(points,3);
```

Here, I assumed that `M(i,j,k) = 1` means that you have measured a point with properties `i`,`j` and `k`, which in your case would be velocity, angle and range.